# Ошибка vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [3] Unknown method passed

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

**Код:**

```py
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(
    token=token)
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpool = VkLongPoll(vk_session)


print("Бот успешно запущен")


def send_some_msg(id, some_text):
    vk_session.method('message.send', {'user_id': id, "message": some_text, "random_id": 0})


for event in longpool.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            msg = event.text.lower()
            id = event.user_id
            send_some_msg(id, 'привет')
```

**Ошибка**:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\drokt\Desktop\Projects\ReadyMade_Bots\Vk\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    send_some_msg(id, 'привет')
  File "C:\Users\drokt\Desktop\Projects\ReadyMade_Bots\Vk\main.py", line 14, in send_some_msg
    vk_session.method('message.send', {'user_id': id, "message": some_text, "random_id": 0})
  File "C:\Users\drokt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 697, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [3] Unknown method passed
```

Comment: `message.send` замени на `messages.send` https://dev.vk.com/ru/method/messages.send

Comment: @evo Напишите в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В API нет такого метода, как `message`, есть `messages`

https://dev.vk.com/ru/method/messages.send

Замените метод на правильный.